# AppEngine "Google-managed, auto-renewing" SSL Certificates on Custom Subdomain Incorrectly Route Content

Tags: google-app-engine, https

I have a Google Cloud project running AppEngine with app id `myapp`. I've mapped this app id to the custom domain `example.com`. I've set the default version of `myapp` to `www`. It has the `secure: always` applied for all handlers in my app.yaml. This setting is used to redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS. Finally, I added CNAME record for `www.example.com`. For each of these routes I've allowed Google to manage and auto-renew SSL Certificates. The settings panel looks like this:

[image: App Engine Domains - Settings Panel]

This is great because all of the HTTP requests get routed to their corresponding HTTPS endpoint.

**A few days ago, I was asked to make a new version of the app `alpha` and want to route that to `https://alpha.example.com`.** Like the `www` version I set `secure: always` to enforce HTTPS redirects for alternate protocols. I also added a CNAME record for alpha.example.com and added the "Google-managed, auto-renewing" certificate to it. `http://alpha.example.com` correctly redirects to `https://alpha.example.com` but, `https://alpha.example.com` serves the default version of my application `www` instead of my new version `alpha`. New settings look like this in the App Engine Custom Domains dashboard:

[image: App Engine Domains - Settings Panel with new Subdomain]

What can I do to ensure `http(s)?://(www)?.example.com` serves version `www`, `http(s)?://alpha.example.com` serves version `alpha`, and ensure all content is served over https?

Comment: This was originally posted, but put on hold over on ServerFault. I was asked to post elsewhere because it was off topic there. Original link can be found [here](https://serverfault.com/posts/925047/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [custom domain docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains#wildcard_mappings):

> Entering `*.example.com` maps all subdomains of example.com to your app.

This means that you'll have to manually handle your mappings in a [`dispatch.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml) file.

In your case, you'll want something like:

```
dispatch:
  - url: "alpha.example.com/"
    service: alpha
  - url: "*.example.com/"
    service: default
```

Be careful with the ordering of your rules, since the requests will be routed according to the first `url` pattern matched.

For a more in-depth explanation of how GAE standard routes requests, check the [How Requests are Routed](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed) doc.

To keep the requests being redirected to the `https` version of the app, keep using the `secure` directive in your [`app.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref).

Comment: Thanks so much! I wasn't aware of dispatch.yaml. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but this totally solved the issue! Thanks!